# How do I set an SSL certificate for Resque on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, resque

I'm trying to debug a failed job on a production environment version of Resque because this is all the web interface gives me to work with:

```
Worker:      9c9fe9d3-8ee0-43fe-afcd-c6806fc75f0d:2 on sentiment_pull at just now
Class:       SentimentJob
Arguments:   [16, 17, 18]13
Exception:   OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError
Error:       SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

This works in development and I'm not sure why I'd get an OpenSSL error on Heroku. I am also using Omniauth so in that initializer I have already set:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do  
  provider #...
  :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_path => "/etc/ssl/certs"}}
end
```

I haven't found any examples of Resque requiring an SSL certificate on Heroku so I'm a bit stumped because the job is set to do requests on an HTTPS URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently had this problem and despite there being plenty of answers out there on how to fix it, this was the only one that worked for me (I'm not on Heroku but instead a Debian VPS).  This is a bad idea most of the time but is fine for my usage case where I need to accept self-signed SSL records.

```
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

This will cause OpenSSL to not verify SSL records and will suppress the error.

Comment: I've seen this answer, I really don't think this is a good idea.

Comment: I agree, it isn't an answer but more of a workaround.  However for me it was the solution I needed as I cannot be positive that every customer will have a CA signed cert.

Comment: So with this, I get `warning: already initialized constant VERIFY_PEER` but my concern is it it disables VERIFY_PEER for other parts of the app that do need to verify (like OmniAuth).